# sap.m.table has json binding table has input field, how to capture input entry

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a table with n number of items. That is being used as Item during deep create operation. This table doen't have multi select mode on. Table is binding initially with json model data for example 2 fields. For one field that is input type have entered something and keep pushing rows using add button. I am getting data for all the fields except this input field that I entered manually. 
I also tried one thing to use liveChange/change on input field but that also seems to working. it erased the data after entry.

```
columns>
        <Column id="col1" minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" hAlign="Center" width="25%">
         <header>
          <Label text="Name" id="lab1" width="25%"/>
         </header>
        </Column>
        <Column id="col2" minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" hAlign="Center" width="75%">
         <header>
          <Label text="employee ID" id="lab2" width="75%"/>
         </header>
        </Column>
       </columns>
<items>
        <ColumnListItem id="item1" type="Active">
         <cells>
          <Text text="{path: 'keyTable>name'}" id="text1" width="5%"/>
          <Input value="{path: 'keyTable>empid'}" id="text2" editable="true"liveChange="readFileObject" width="95%"></Input>
         </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
       </items>

readFileObject: function(oEvent){
   //lv_BusyDialog.open();
   var that = this;
   var items = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext("keyTable").getObject();

   var sPath = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext("keyTable").getPath();
   var sPath1 = sPath.split("/");
   var x = parseInt(sPath1[2]) + 1;

   var name =items.NAME;
   var empid=items.EMPID;

    var newData = {
       NAME:name,
      EMPID: empid};

      that.getView().getModel("keyTable").setProperty(sPath, newData);


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like oEvent.getParameters("newValue") or oEvent.mParameters.newValue. 
Do not use that, if you you want to keep the this context, for example:

```
error: function (oError) {
                    this._resetViewModel();
                    MessageToast.show(oError);
                }.bind(this)
```

Comment: Thanks Niels..where exactly I have to put the suggested code?

Comment: As I am doing the same way to get the value entered in the input field but instaed of new data update data is getting erased on enter.